# Multiple movements with keyboard in C++

Tags: c++, keyboard

Im trying to get my movement of a ball to just move in a fluid like motion. How can I have it that when I press the up key, down key, left key, or right key, it doesnt move up one unit, stop, then keep moving. Also, how can i have it move in two directions at the same time wthout stopping another direction when letting off a key?
Thanks

```
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP))
{
    if(g_nGameState == SETTINGUPSHOT_GAMESTATE || g_nGameState == INITIAL_GAMESTATE)
    {
        g_cObjectWorld.AdjustCueBallY(MOVEDELTA);
        g_cObjectWorld.ResetImpulseVector();
    }
}

if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN))
{
    if(g_nGameState == SETTINGUPSHOT_GAMESTATE || g_nGameState == INITIAL_GAMESTATE)
    {
        g_cObjectWorld.AdjustCueBallY(-MOVEDELTA);
        g_cObjectWorld.ResetImpulseVector();
    }
}

if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT))
{
    if(g_nGameState == SETTINGUPSHOT_GAMESTATE || g_nGameState == INITIAL_GAMESTATE)
    {
        g_cObjectWorld.AdjustCueBallX(-MOVEDELTA);
        g_cObjectWorld.ResetImpulseVector();
    }
}

if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT))
{
    if(g_nGameState == SETTINGUPSHOT_GAMESTATE || g_nGameState == INITIAL_GAMESTATE)
    {
        g_cObjectWorld.AdjustCueBallX(MOVEDELTA);
        g_cObjectWorld.ResetImpulseVector();
    }
}
```

Comment: Normally the problem with the delayed repeat action would be with not checking the right bits in `GetAsyncKeyState` return, but as I can see, you're checking them all for positive value, so the problem is probably somewhere else beyond the code you provided on your post...

Comment: Many prehistoric (pre-windowing) games used other keys for the diagonal moves.  See 'robots' console game.  Slightly more modern console games will use the keypad where '5' is the center and '9' would be up and right.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

Use SetTimer to create a timer on your window event loop 10ms interval should be good for what you want. The reason it has to be on the window thread is that GetAsyncKeyState will not give you the desired results when called from a different thread.
We use a timer since the call to GetAsyncKeyState should be on a different message then the key processing events so the key is still in the queue.

Within the timer function you can do something like this

```
int deltaX = 0, deltaY = 0;

unsigned int downDown = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN);
unsigned int upDown = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP);
unsigned int leftDown = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT);
unsigned int rightDown = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT);

if(downDown & 0x00008000)deltaY -= MOVEDELTA;
if(upDown & 0x00008000)deltaY += MOVEDELTA;
if(leftDown & 0x00008000)deltaX -= MOVEDELTA;
if(rightDown & 0x00008000)deltaX += MOVEDELTA;

g_cObjectWorld.AdjustCueBallX(deltaX);
g_cObjectWorld.AdjustCueBallY(deltaY);
g_cObjectWorld.ResetImpulseVector();
```

In this way you can also make sure that the movement stops on keyup (deltaX == 0 && deltaY == 0)
I'm not sure what are the semantics of AdjustCueBall(X|Y) but if you make sure they stop moving in that direction when they get 0 it should work just fine.

Also you should notice that your keyboard must support multiple key press in the hardware for you to be able to move diagonally using two keys - If it does the solution above will work if it doesn't you will still be able to move in either one of the four fundamental directions.

Answer (score 0):

One design is to use the keyboard only for **changing** directions.

Let the ball continue in its present direction until a keypress is received that would change its direction.  This reduces the load on the processor from continuously being interrupted by keypresses.

As for going in non-orthogonal directions, use more keys.  Look at a "keypad".  Some keys are diagonal from the '5' keys.  Use those.